# Why not use a URL as a password?

Tags: passwords

When picking a password for a site, is it a good idea to use an unrelated URL, such as `http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_injection.asp`, as the password?

I can see some benefits - it's hard to bruteforce, it's not personal information, and it's easy to rembember. But since I have never heard anyone recommend it, I asume there are some downsides?

Comment: In post-quantum era, you should have random passwords of some minimum length, the longer the better. URL is not random and that's the problem. Anyway, the example URL is very weak password - the entropy is very low as it's made of dictionary words.

Comment: Is it easy to remember? If website changes url scheme, you can't just google it. It is good password but I do not see point of it. It can be just sftp://myname@mydomain.com. Still no one would guess it. Hard to bruteforce but it is just 'random' characters. Overall url is good password, but websites isn't password managers

Comment: in short, your password should not contain any meaning, a dictionary word or a predictable arrangements of certain characters. Strongest passwords are those that don't make any sense, not even to the owner.

Comment: what about something like this which has gobbledygook as part of its characteristics? https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GUEA_enSG644SG644

Answer (score 9):

Whether this is a good or a bad idea depends on what kind of password this URL password replaces.

An URL is a usually a fairly long string; the example string is 46 characters long. This makes a simple brute-force attack (e.g. try every single combination of letters, digits and special characters) infeasible and an url like the above one is thus a much better password than one that consists of just a string of 6 fully random letters, digits and special characters.

The above URL is also a better password than the ones that are generally posted in "the ten million most common passwords" etc. The example URL contains at least 4 words - w3schools, sql, injection and asp. Them being dictionary words isn't really a problem. If each of these words was chosen *randomly* out of a pool of, say, 10000 possible words (this is a lower bound; there are way more than 10000 available domains and many more than 10000 words - this includes the URL of this question, which includes the id '143283' - so that's a million possibilities right there), you'd have a password equivalent to about 53 random bits. That's not including any special characters (e.g. where the slashes and underscores are, which would add a few additional bits). 53 bits isn't safe from brute forcing any more, but it's way, way better than most passwords users select (123456, password, loveyou, Maria, EatMyBackside and so on). So you might be safe simply because other passwords would be cracked before yours (you don't have to run faster than a lion to escape him - you just need to run faster than your peers...)

Now to the **problems**: The first one is that an URL is, contrary to what you say, kind of personal information. In order to use the URL, you need to know that it exists, e.g. you must have visited it at least once. This is information that could be extracted from sources other than you; for example, if your browser history was captured, chances are good your password URL would be part of it. Someone might also arrive at the URL (or at least at part of it) by eavesdropping on your web browsing and looking at which sites you visit. It would then be a simple job to have a spider crawl all the valid urls on these sites and feed them into a password guesser.

The second one is that while the space of all URLs is fairly big, it's not as big as you'd think. Also, not all domains are equally likely to be the source of your password URL; for example, it's a fairly safe bet you know reddit and craigslist and stackexchange, but that you've never visited the website of the university of Vienna. So even if I can't get at your browser history, and even though I can't check every single URL out there, I can still select likely domain names (say, the 50000 most visited domains) and crawl them, thus increasing my chance that I'll find your password.

The third one is that the math I did to arrive at the password size of 53 bits assumes that the words found in an URL are *unrelated* and chosen *randomly*. As you can see with your example URL, the words w3schools, sql, injection and asp are hardly unrelated; they all belong to a cluster of words having to do with the web. Many urls will sport such words taken from a word cluster, thus further reducing the number of combinations I have to try.

So, no, an URL is not a good replacement for a secure password (e.g. a very long one with a strong random element). But still, it's much better than your basic six-letter dictionary word.

Comment: What if you add "query?password=trustNo1" to the password (with a random password) would the entropy increase?

Comment: Also how would the attacker know if you're using urls, song lyrics, book excerpts, maybe combine lyrics + an url + a poem, I you choose long enough sentences, I can't imagine them being cracked any time soon

Comment: What if you just base64 the contents of that url and use that as a password, even if the password is nonrandom, I don't see how an attacker could find out.